# recyclerview not show multiple data from Json

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

my recyclerview show one data but i receive multiple data in logcat in the form of json

Here is main file

Stitle.java

```
 package com.desktop.app;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;



public class Stitle extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText searchtitle;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
    private List<list> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter listAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stitle);


        searchtitle = findViewById(R.id.searchtitle);
        searchtitle.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

                    foji();
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smain);
                    listAdapter = new listAdapter(Stitle.this,productList);
                    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)  findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    // use a linear layout manager
                    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Stitle.this);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        }

    public void foji(){
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("http")
                .authority("192.168.0.136")
                .appendPath("fyp")
                .appendPath("stitle.php")
                .appendQueryParameter("Title",searchtitle.getText().toString());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, builder.build().toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("Info",response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("search");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject product=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        boolean add = productList.add(new list(
                                product.getLong("isbn"),
                                product.getString("title"),
                                product.getString("authors"),
                                product.getInt("accession"),
                                product.getString("publisher"),
                                product.getInt("pubyear"),
                                product.getInt("pages"),
                                product.getInt("rak"),
                                product.getInt("hr"),
                                product.getInt("vr"),
                                product.getLong("barcode")

                        ));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Stitle.this, "Foji Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Here is file for setter and getter

list.java

```
    package com.desktop.app;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class list implements Serializable {
    private long isbn;
    private String title;
    private String authors;
    private int accession;
    private String publisher;
    private int pubyear;
    private int pages;
    private int rak;
    private int hr;
    private int vr;
    private long barcode;


    public list(long isbn, String title, String authors, int accession, String publisher, int pubyear, int pages, int rak, int hr, int vr, long barcode) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.accession = accession;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.pubyear = pubyear;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.rak = rak;
        this.hr = hr;
        this.vr = vr;
        this.barcode = barcode;

    }


    public long getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public int getAccession() {
        return accession;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public int getPubyear(){
        return pubyear;
    }

    public int getPages(){
        return pages;
    }

    public int getRak(){
        return rak;
    }

    public int getHr(){
        return hr;
    }

    public int getVr(){
        return vr;
    }

    public long getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }


    public void setIsbn(long isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthors(String authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public void setAccession(int accession) {
        this.accession = accession;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void setPubyear(int pubyear) {
        this.pubyear = pubyear;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public void setRak(int rak) {
        this.rak = rak;
    }

    public void setHr(int hr) {
        this.hr = hr;
    }

    public void setVr(int vr) {
        this.vr = vr;
    }

    public void setBarcode(long barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }
}
```

Here is file of lisAdapter

listAdapter.java

```
    package com.desktop.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.List;


public class listAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<listAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    RequestOptions options ;
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<list> pdata;

    listAdapter(Context mCtx, List productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.pdata = productList;
    }


    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slist,parent,false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        list product = pdata.get(position);

        holder.textviewisbn.setText(String.valueOf(product.getIsbn()));
        holder.textviewtitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.textviewauthors.setText(product.getAuthors());
        holder.textviewacc.setText(String.valueOf(product.getAccession()));
        holder.textviewpublisher.setText(product.getPublisher());
        holder.textviewpubyear.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPubyear()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pdata.size();
    }

    public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textviewisbn, textviewtitle, textviewauthors, textviewacc, textviewpublisher, textviewpubyear;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textviewisbn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewisbn);
            textviewtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewtitle);
            textviewauthors = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewauthors);
            textviewacc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewacc);
            textviewpublisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewpublisher);
            textviewpubyear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewpubyear);

        }
    }
}
```

slist.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewisbn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/textviewtitle"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewauthors"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewtitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewacc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewauthors"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewpublisher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewacc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewpubyear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewpublisher"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

recylerview xml file

activity_smain.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.desktop.app.listactivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylcerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="745dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-51dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Recyclerview show one data but i receive multiple data in logcat in the form of json
>
> I/Info:     {"status":true,"search":[{"isbn":195472462,"title":"Oxford Practice Grammer","authors":"john Eastwood","accession":1,"publisher":"Ameena Saiyid Oxford University","pubyear":2014,"pages":432,"rak":1,"hr":1,"vr":1,"barcode":195472462},{"isbn":9694946719,"title":"High School English Grammer ","authors":"Wren, martin","accession":4,"publisher":"Paramount Publishing","pubyear":2010,"pages":418,"rak":1,"hr":1,"vr":4,"barcode":9694946719}]}
>
> this data recieve as json but only one record show in list [image show's that only one record on list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wHGV.jpg)

Comment: post your xml file used as item in recyclerview.. Are you able to see another items on scroll of a list?

Comment: first check your list size i think your error is in adding data in list

Comment: yes @VishvaDave show data on scroll of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can see the data on scroll because you have set the list item height to 
>   `match_parent`.. you just need to set it to `wrap_content`

**slist.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewisbn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/textviewtitle"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewauthors"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewtitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewacc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewauthors"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewpublisher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewacc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewpubyear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textviewpublisher"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @AsadMallick Happy to help :) Happy coding :)

Comment: can you help me more @ Vishva Dave.. i want to open new activity and show more data on click on one result in list

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=recycler+view+item+click+and+data+pass+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=3g8&channel=fs&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2oMec-LvbAhXEuo8KHcCmCjUQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1280&bih=842

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787887/click-on-list-data-to-show-data-to-new-activity-using-recyclerview) 
I posted this problem @Vishva Dave